# How can I read HTML using Selenium in Python when I cannot see the whole page?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I want to use some text in a Smartsheet **page/grid**, but when I try to access it using Selenium (finding the element by id and copying the text to a variable), the text only includes the cells of the grid that fit in the web window.
So, for example, the code I have will grab all columns [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x3ni.png), up to column 7, and all rows up to 20.  But column 8 and rows after 20, [seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSvDD.png), will not be grabbed by the code:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://app.smartsheetgov.com/sheets/54hPp4faksdjfhk46jJwMqqWxChg55GXG6Jmc1?view=grid")
    
# this will loop until the user logs in to the website
column_names_object = None
while column_names_object == None:
    try:
        column_names_object = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "foid:23")))
    except TimeoutException:
        print('Please login to Smartsheet')

column_names = column_names_object.text.split("\n")
number_of_columns = len(column_names)

grid = driver.find_element(By.ID,"foid:18")
grid_rows = grid.text.split("\n ")
number_of_rows = len(grid_rows)
```

How do I get the text that is in the rest of the spreadsheet without having Selenium scroll and read the element multiple times?

I have tried zooming out to 26%, it somewhat works when I do it manually while debugging, but not when running the code by itself (with driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='26%'"))

To be clear, the code does get the text attribute of the column_names_object, the problem is that the object does not have the whole text.  The same with the grid object.

Comment: can you share the link of your application?

did you try to use getAttribute() method instead of getText()?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.